# how to make a workflow flow based on different rules

Tags: email, salesforce, workflow

I am attempting to create a workflow rule but am running into syntax errors. I would like the workflow to fire if the record type is equal to "Athlete", "Coach", or "Judge", the Profile Status is equal to "Active", and the Medical Exam Date is equal to today. This is what I have so far:

IF
(AND(RecordType.Name == 'Athlete',Profile_*r.Status*_c == 'Active') ,  TODAY()  =    Medical_Exame_Date)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are few cases where you would need to use an `IF(condition, iftrue, iffalse)` in a workflow. When the workflow is evaluated, it's just looking for the entire condition to return true or false. I think this may be what you're looking for:

```
AND(
    OR(
        RecordType.Name == 'Athlete',
        RecordType.Name == 'Coach',
        RecordType.Name == 'Judge'
    ),
    Profile__r.Status__c == 'Active',
    Medical_Exame_Date__c == TODAY()
)
```